# Faster way to convert dataframe columns to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

There is a small script that I wrote to convert my dataframe columns into a JSON object. But I have written it in such a way that it converts row by row, stores it in a list and then converts it back to a Dataframe with only one column holding this JSON data.

```
data_q=[]
for i in temporary_Data.index:
    #print(temporary_Data.loc[i])
    data=temporary_Data.loc[i].to_json()
    data_q.append(data)
df=pd.DataFrame(data_q)
df.columns=['RuleType3']
```

This is very very slow. My dataframe size could be very large going up to 1M records. Is there any way I can improve this now? Thank you

Comment: why you converting df to json and then again to df? do you customize anything in it?

Comment: When I insert this dataframe into the table, I need it in JSON format instead of column-wise information.

Comment: you can convert this "temporary_Data" dataframe into json . but why do you iterate. i mean didnt understand its structure... because you iterate "temporary_Data" but passing its each index into variables of iterate itself.. seems something wrong in it.. otherwise show the mock of your structure

Comment: There is an ID column with respect to which this JSON for each column is created. I want to keep that structure as it is. The output should be 
`ID`  `data`

  1      {"column1":"sdjbskdb","column2":"djbfvkjb"}

Comment: `temporary_Data.to_json()`